# is there an way to transform key field values to lower case in debezium sql server source connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I want to transform SQL-Server column names to lower case while storing it in a Kafka topic. I am using debezium as my source connector

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to achieve in a specific line of code (or a few of them): https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using Kafka Connect Common Transformations by Jeremy Custenborder

SQL Server table:

```
Id  Name Description  Weight Pro_Id
101 aaa  Sample_Test  3.14   2020-02-21 13:32:06.5900000
102 eee  testdata1    3.14   2020-02-21 13:32:06.5900000
```

Step 1: Download the kafka connect common transformations jar file by Jeremy Custenborder in confluent hub from this [link](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-common)

Step 2: place the jar file in /usr/share/java or /kafka/libs based on your kafka environment

Step 3: Create the debezium SQL-Server source connector

```
{
  "name": "sqlserver_src_connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
    "database.server.name": "sqlserver",
    "database.hostname": "*.*.*.*",
    "database.port": "1433",
    "database.user": "username",
    "database.password": "password",
    "database.dbname": "db_name",
    "table.whitelist": "dbo.tablename",
    "transforms": "unwrap,changeCase",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.changeCase.type" : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.common.ChangeCase$Value",
    "transforms.changeCase.from" : "UPPER_UNDERSCORE",
    "transforms.changeCase.to" : "LOWER_UNDERSCORE",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "*.*.*.*",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes-tablename"
  }
}
```

Step 4: kafka topic data

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "int32",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "id"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "name"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "description"
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "weight"
      },
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": false,
        "name": "io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "pro_id"
      }
    ],
    "optional": true,
    "name": "sqlserver.dbo.tablename"
  },
  "payload": {
    "id": 101,
    "name": "aaa",
    "description": "Sample_Test",
    "weight": 3.14,
    "pro_id": 1582291926590000000
  }
}
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "int32",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "id"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "name"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "description"
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "weight"
      },
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": false,
        "name": "io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp",
        "version": 1,
        "field": "pro_id"
      }
    ],
    "optional": true,
    "name": "sqlserver.dbo.tablename"
  },
  "payload": {
    "id": 102,
    "name": "eee",
    "description": "testdata1",
    "weight": 3.14,
    "pro_id": 1582291926590000000
  }
}
```

thanks for the help [Jiri Pechanec](https://github.com/jpechane) and Chris Cranford @Naros from [debezium community](https://gitter.im/debezium/user#)

Comment: You should probably mark this as accepted.